# ImageVector vs. renderMode: 'image' vs. selection style in OpenLayers 4.6

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

After upgrading my code from `ol.layer.Image` and `ol.source.ImageVector` to `ol.layer.Vector` with `renderMode: 'image'`, as described in the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.6.0), I noticed that the behaviour concerning selections has changed:

Before the upgrade selections were displayed on top of all the other layers. All representations of the selected feature stayed in place. Now the selection seems to replace all other representations.

I have created a fiddle to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4ke2ad0j/47/

We have two layers:

- `layerOutline`: a normal vector layer displaying the feature's outline, used for select interaction
- `layerText`: a description layer which displays a label attribute from the feature's properties

`layerText` is created in two different ways: One uses the new `renderMode: 'image'` and the other one uses an `ImageVector`. The one using the new mode disappears on selection:

[image: Different implementations with a selected feature]

Does anyone have an idea how to get back the old behaviour without using the deprecated `ImageVector`?

Changing the select's `StyleFunction` is not an option, because I need a single style for a lot of different feature representations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ImageVector layer is a layer that is drawn as an image and not refresh on selection. Thus you can see the selected feature drawn under the selection.

The Vector layer is redrawn on selection and the selected feature is not thus you just can see the selection with the selected style.

So the select's StyleFunction is your only option.

If you need a lot of representation you can call the default style function in your select StyleFunction and push a new style over it:

```
// style used for selection (should be an overlay to be the most flexible)
function styleSelect(feature, resolution) {
  // Call the default style
  var style = [ styleText(feature, resolution) ];
  // Add red outline
  var outline = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 2,
      color: '#f00'
    })   
  });
  style.push(outline);
  return style;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Viglino/zz2t9jdf/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs, because I cannot merge all appearances of my feature down to one layer.

I use one source on multiple layers using different style functions. Those layers may be switched on and off separately. If I set a selection, I would expect only the selection layer to be affected, not the other layers containing the same feature.

Defining a selection style like in your approach would mean, I had to check all layers containng the feature for visibility and add their specific styles to my selection style. That doesn't seem right.